# Exclude comments from search results in IntelliJ global search?

Tags: search, intellij-idea, find, comments

I found the grammar error "it's" as a possessive on one page of a large project. I'm trying to search for any other usages of this on pages to correct it, but I'm getting results containing hundreds of comments. I just want to filter for the important user-facing portions of the project. Is there a way to exclude comments from the results of a global search?

Comment: Is it a string literal or part JSP page?

Comment: It could be either, though most of the problematic ones would probably be on JSPs.

Comment: It's difficult to suggest something without really looking at the code, but since it seems like a one-off thing, I would use global search just in comments to temporary replace "it's" with some #temporary-token#, then use global search everywhere, you should everything what's left. Then rollback temporary token for comments. Should be easy to try with VCS. Just an idea.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, but that brings me back to the same question, how would I use global search to replace "it's" just in comments?

Comment: Added screenshots to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to suggest something without really looking at the code, but since it seems like a one-off thing, I would use global search just in comments to temporary replace "it's" with some #temporary-token#, then use global search everywhere, you should everything what's left. Then rollback temporary token for comments. Should be easy to try with VCS. Just an idea.

[image]

As you can see, with "Comments only" option, only one #token is found.

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I don't have that option. What version of IntelliJ are you running?

Comment: I'm running 13.0.1, build 133.331, you did not mentioned the version in your question, so I assumed that you are running latest. I don't have other versions handy to check the option availability. I can check later today.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm on version 12. Waiting for my employer to get the 13 license still. I guess I'll just have to postpone this until we upgrade. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can download 13.x with 30 days of trial license. Or download Common and keep it as long as you want.

Answer (score 11):

In more recent versions, at least in PyCharm 2018 (similar to IntelliJ), there is a filter option "Except comments," as shown here:

[image: screenshot of find-in-path dialog with filter options]

(Click the small filter icon to show the dropdown.)

Note: The selected filter option persists during a session, and the active filter option is not immediately apparent unless you open the dropdown. To prevent accidentally limiting subsequent searches, it may be a good idea to switch back to "Anywhere" afterward.

Another approach would be to enable the "Regular expression" (or "Regex") checkbox in the search dialog, then use some kind of negative lookaround to exclude comments.

In one case, I needed to exclude lines with single-line comments (e.g. `# this is a comment`) from a search, but not lines with inline comments (e.g. `a=b+1 # this is an inline comment`). The following did the trick, searching for `something` (for Python comments, starting with `#`):

`^((?!#).)*something.*$`

Please note I'm not a regex-expert, so this regex pattern can probably be improved upon greatly, but it illustrates the idea. You can play around with this on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tt1Roo). Any comments to improve the pattern are most welcome, of course.

Note sure if this approach could be extended to multiline comments though. (as in `""" several lines here """`).